# Clone & Append Link to Container, but Append the entire URL — Not the Link Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This should be easy but I can't find any topics about this, I think it's because I don't know how to phrase it correctly.

**Problem:**

When you hover over a link it gets cloned & appended to #container — however I want the link in #container to be the actual URL in its entirety, so if a link text says: ["here is an article"](http://http:/www.myarticle.com/name-of-article), I want the one that gets appended to #container to show: [http:/www.myarticle.com/name-of-article](http://http:/www.myarticle.com/name-of-article).

I've tried to make my question very visually clear on CodePen, would someone check it out and advice me? :-)

http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/YqNrYO

The jQuery I use:

```
$('a').one('mouseover', function(){

 $(this).clone().appendTo('#container'); 
});
```

Either JavaScript or jQuery solutions are fine, I use both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the link text to the value of the href attribute.

```
$('a').one('mouseover', function(){
 var href = $(this).attr('href'); 
 $(this).clone().text(href).appendTo('#container');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZgeNe

Comment: That's perfect! I tried with .attr but i forgot to use text before appendTo doh! Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```
$('a').one('mouseover', function(){
     $('#container').append($(this).attr('href')); 
});
```

You need to catch the attribute of the link, which is done by using `attr('attribute-handle')`